# Jetty offline documentation

Tags: java, jetty

Is there any more-or-less comprehensive documentation for Jetty (e.g., similar to Tomcat or, really, in any form)? Theirs online wikis seems to be quite informative, but servers seem to be slow. Maybe, there some way to build docs from Jetty source distribution? I tried `mvn site` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu you could try installing the libjetty-java-doc package. There's likely similar options for other OSes.